# php array in an sql query between date

Tags: php, mysql

I have this $option Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 10 )

My query is:

```
$query = "SELECT *  FROM table WHERE cc_classification IN ('" . implode("','",$options) . "') AND submit_date BETWEEN '2015-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-10 23:59:59'  ";
```

Not sure what is wrong with this query but it gave me nothing in result.

I tried to take out the date range

```
$query = "SELECT *  FROM table WHERE cc_classification IN ('" . implode("','",$options) . "') ";
```

and it's working fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Problem i not in array, but in sql syntax.

```
$query = "SELECT *  FROM table WHERE cc_classification IN ('" . implode("','",$options) . "') AND (submit_date BETWEEN '2015-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-10 23:59:59')  ";
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel but no dice still. However, I tried with another DATETIME column with the same sql query and it worked fine. For example: `$query = "SELECT *  FROM table WHERE cc_classification IN ('" . implode("','",$options) . "') AND (added_date BETWEEN '2015-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-10 23:59:59')  "; ` . **Note** two column are same DATETIME field. Only different is that "submit_date" filed has some rows such as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 (date will update when approval submitted) vs "added_date" field has no such 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Don't think it's an issue but wanted to point out. Thanks.